# start time series data when there are no NaN's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have some time series data that I applied a rolling mean on with a window of 17520.

Thus before the head of my data looked like this:

```
SETTLEMENTDATE  ==
0  2006/01/01 00:30:00  8013.27833   ...     5657.67500    20.03
1  2006/01/01 01:00:00  7726.89167   ...     5460.39500    18.66
2  2006/01/01 01:30:00  7372.85833   ...     5766.02500    20.38
3  2006/01/01 02:00:00  7071.83333   ...     5503.25167    18.59
4  2006/01/01 02:30:00  6865.44000   ...     5214.01500    17.53
```

And now it looks like this:

```
        SETTLEMENTDATE  =
0  2006/01/01 00:30:00         NaN   ...            NaN      NaN
1  2006/01/01 01:00:00         NaN   ...            NaN      NaN
2  2006/01/01 01:30:00         NaN   ...            NaN      NaN
3  2006/01/01 02:00:00         NaN   ...            NaN      NaN
4  2006/01/01 02:30:00         NaN   ...            NaN      NaN
```

How can I get it so that my data only begins, when there is not a NaN? (also making sure that the date matches)

## =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `rolling` with `min_periods = 1`

```
data['NSW DEMAND'] = data['NSW DEMAND'].rolling(17520,min_periods=17520).mean()
```

Also try using for loo, you do not need to write the columns one by one

```
youcols=['xxx'...'xxx1']
for x in youcols:
    data[x]=data[x].rolling(17520,min_periods=1).mean()
```

---

Base on your comments

```
for x in youcols:
    data[x]=data[x].rolling(17520,min_periods=1).mean()
```

then ,

```
data=data.dropna(subset=youcols,thresh =1)
```

Comment: I edited my question to show you what happens when I run your code

Comment: @newtoR let me ad a little bit more info, you still need store the columns you want to using rolling into a list

Comment: The first entry should be on settlement date 1/01/2007, except my first entry actually is 1/01/2006

Comment: @newtoR is dropna you need ?

Comment: I think it might be but the script is still running?

Comment: Taking verylong

Comment: Drop NA fixed it!

Comment: However I reverted back to listing out each column by column, using your .apply lambda thing really slowed it

Comment: @newtoR no matter what, I think you just need add dropna at the end , let me know whether it work for you or not

Comment: Drop NA worked, however your `data[youcols]=data[youcols].apply(lambda x : x.rolling(17520,min_periods=17520).mean(),axis=1)
` didnt

Comment: @newtoR let me change that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187086/discussion-between-newtor-and-w-b).